# ReactJS Classes How to pass State from Child Component to its Parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I will call the LI tags like this (li) so they are not made into bullet points for his question

Hi I am trying to send a Child component to its Parent in ReactJS.

I tried many things I managed to send the child component state back up to its Parent props but when the page renders I have a couple of (li) tags which I want the update to update with it for example like:

(li) hard coded text (/li)
(li) old text (/li)
(li) update prop (/li)
(li) update prop etc (/li)

but instead the update deletes all previous code so it looks like:

(li) update prop deleted all previous li's (/li)

Hope that made sense here is my code

Parent Component

```
    import React from 'react';
import { generateId, getNewExpirationTime } from '../../util/utilities';
import Thought from '../Thought/Thought.js'
import AddThoughtForm from '../AddThoughtForm/AddThoughtForm.js'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      thoughts: [{
        id: generateId(),
        text: 'This is a place for your passing thoughts.',
        expiresAt: getNewExpirationTime()
      },
      {
      id: generateId(),
      text: "They'll be removed after 15 seconds.",
      expiresAt: getNewExpirationTime()
    }]
  };
    this.addThought = this.addThought.bind(this);
    this.removeThought = this.removeThought.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.componentDidUpdate = this.componentDidUpdate.bind(this);
  }
  addThought(thought) {
   
    console.log("LOOK")
    console.log(thought)
    console.log("DONE")

    console.log(this.state.thoughts);
    this.state.thoughts.push(thought);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      ...prevState,
      thoughts: [thought] 
    }))
    console.log("passed over")
    console.log(this.state.thoughts);
 
  }
  removeThought(selected) {
    //alert('selected');
    let updatedThoughts = this.state.thoughts.filter((thought) => selected.id !== thought.id);
    return this.setState({ thoughts: updatedThoughts })

}

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header>
          <h1>Passing Thoughts</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
         <AddThoughtForm 
          addThought={this.addThought}
          thoughts={this.state.thoughts} />
          <ul className="thoughts">
            {(this.state.thoughts) && this.state.thoughts.map((thought, index) => (
              <Thought 
                key={thought.id} 
                thought={thought}
                removeThought={this.removeThought} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }  
  
}
```

Still on the Parent Component my .addThought(arg) is where the action is. This is where I'm sending the Child AddThoughtForm state object into it. By inside of .addThought() I am doing this:

```
addThought(thought) {

console.log("LOOK")
console.log(thought)
console.log("DONE")

console.log(this.state.thoughts);
this.state.thoughts.push(thought);
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  ...prevState,
  thoughts: [thought] 
}))
console.log("passed over")
console.log(this.state.thoughts);
}
```

What happens is when I pass it over my previous State of my parent is deleted and replaced by this new information from my child component. How do I stop that? I want to only add this new Information to the previous info that the Parent state already have. here is the state from my parent:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      thoughts: [{
        id: generateId(),
        text: 'This is a place for your passing thoughts.',
        expiresAt: getNewExpirationTime()
      },
      {
      id: generateId(),
      text: "They'll be removed after 15 seconds.",
      expiresAt: getNewExpirationTime()
    }]
  };
    this.addThought = this.addThought.bind(this);
    this.removeThought = this.removeThought.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.componentDidUpdate = this.componentDidUpdate.bind(this);
  }
```

Now over to the Child Component

AddThoughtForm.js

```
 import React from 'react';
import { generateId, getNewExpirationTime } from '../../util/utilities';

class AddThoughtForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ideas: [this.props.thoughts] // I can take off [] 
        }
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleTextChange(event) {
        
        const { value } = event.target
      
      
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let thoughts = Object.assign({}, prevState.ideas);  // creating copy of state variable 
            thoughts.id = generateId();
            thoughts.text = value;                    // update the name property, assign a new value      
            thoughts.expiresAt = getNewExpirationTime();           
            return { thoughts };                                 // return new object 
        })

        
        console.log(this.state.ideas)
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.addThought(this.state.thoughts)
        

        
        alert(this.state.ideas);
     
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="AddThoughtForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        aria-label="What's on your mind?"
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        value={this.state.text}
        onChange={this.handleTextChange}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
        )
    }
}

export default AddThoughtForm;
```

On my .handleTextChange(event) is where I am linking it with my input tag in render so what I am doing what ever Is typed into it I want entered I want it be passed to my Parent Component. well It is passed over but it over-writes the old info every time the old (li) and it is then all just a new li being rendered. Any ideas on how I can fix all of this?

```
handleTextChange(event) {        
        const { value } = event.target
        console.log(value)
       
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let thoughts = Object.assign({}, prevState.ideas);  // creating copy of state variable 
            thoughts.id = generateId();
            thoughts.text = value;                     // update the name property, assign a new value      
            thoughts.expiresAt = getNewExpirationTime();           
            return { thoughts };                                 // return new object 
        })        
        console.log(this.state.ideas)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it

just had to add on the Parent Component a thoughts: [...prevState, thought] as I was overwritting the old thoughts with the new incoming thought
Like this:

In the method, .addThought()

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  ...prevState,
  thoughts: [...prevState.thoughts, thought] 
}))
```